# How to setup wxWidgets under Windows + Eclipse + Cygwin + GCC

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, gcc, wxwidgets

I am trying to use wxWidgets under Windows 7, Eclipse CDT and Cygwin GCC.

Can anyone offer some advice on how to install and compile wxWidgets under that environment?

Comment: I am new to programming, I have installed Eclipse and Cygwin GCC, but have no clue how to install wxWidgets.

Comment: Have you downloaded wxWidgets?  Did you read the instructions on their website?  Why do you think you need wxWidgets if you are brand-new to programming?  Doesn't the book or class you're learning with provide any instructions?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [video tutorial](http://wxwidgets.info/wxwidgets_and_eclipse_video/) which shows the full installation and configuration process.
In video MinGW is used but for Cygwin process should be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Eclipse wxWiki page](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Eclipse). It looks rather old but might still be helpful.